# Embedded Flash (swf) in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, flash

I would like to embed flash animation in swf format in a mediawiki page! Is there any plug-in or built-in support to do this?
I am trying to do it using the following software:
MediaWiki--->1.22.2
PHP--->5.4.12 (apache2handler)
MySQL--->5.6.12-log

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for that: [https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FlvHandler](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aFlvHandler)

Answer (score 0):

In older Mediawiki versions you could use something like the gflash or swf extensions, but they are retired in recent versions due to security concerns.

The most recent and compatible extension like this appears to be https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OFlash

Answer (score -1):

I know it's an old question, but someone else may want to try [this](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OFlash)!